# Create and validate check box programmatically using Java in Android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I need to create a number of check boxes programmatically using Java, check if one of them is checked and when I click **Next Button** the control will move to next page. If none of them is checked a toast message has to be displayed. Please suggest as I am new to Android.

Here is my code:

```
public class TestValidCheckboxActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

private RelativeLayout layoutMiddle = null;
private TableLayout layout1;
private CheckBox chk;
private  String[] resarr = {"silu", "pinky", "meera"};
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    layoutMiddle = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutMiddleUp);
    layout1 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableId1);
    final Button btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    int i = 0;
        for(String res: resarr){
            TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
                chk=new CheckBox(this);
                chk.setId(i);
                chk.setText(res);
                chk.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tr.addView(chk);
                i++;
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, layoutMiddle.getId());
            layout1.addView(tr, lay);
        }
        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg1)
                {
                    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final View view) {
                            Log.e("1111111111","111111111");
                                if(chk.isChecked()){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),NextPage.class);
                                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                                }else{
                                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "please choose at least one option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    msg.show();
                                }

                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(TestValidCheckboxActivity.this, "please choose at least one option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }

        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be easily done
take a boolean flag and set true it on `checkbox.isChecked();`(inbuilt) 
then check if flag is set then navigate to next else TOAST

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us some of your layout code, meaning, are the checkboxes defined in an xml file and do they have IDs?

If they do, you can access each of them with `findViewByID` and check their status one by one.